# Textarea Text not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 functions in my Javascript, the first one receives a JSon from an WebApi takes a string and writes that to a textare, than i change something in that textarea and submit it back to the server, when i select another object from a dropdown it should receive that JSon from the Api.

The following occurs what i find very strange, as long as i dont change anything in the textarea it works just fine receiving every item i want.
The moment i change something in my textarea it doesnt change it anymore when i select another item in the Dropdown, neither does it change after i edited something in the text area without saving it back and select another item from the dropdown while the changes of the other values work just fine.

```
$.getJSON(uri + '/' + id).done(function (data) {                        
    $("#tarea").text(atob(data.xmlString));                                               
    document.getElementById("currentTicket").textContent = "Current Ticket: " + data.TicketID;
    document.getElementById("menu1").textContent = data.TicketID;
    document.getElementById("input").value = data.TicketID;
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) set the value of text area instead of using [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$("#tarea").val(atob(data.xmlString));
```

---

Since you are using jQuery, you can use jQuery methods to set the text contents and value like

```
$.getJSON(uri + '/' + id).done(function (data) {
    $("#tarea").val(atob(data.xmlString));
    $("#currentTicket").text("Current Ticket: " + data.TicketID);
    $("#menu1").text(data.TicketID);
    $("#input").val(data.TicketID);
})
```

Comment: Works like a charm thank you, i tried a lot of different methods to find the right one couldnt think of $("#name").val.

Answer (score 2):

Convert this

```
$("#tarea").text(atob(data.xmlString))
```

to this

```
$("#tarea").val(atob(data.xmlString))
```

Answer (score 2):

use `.val()` for all input types

and `.text()` for span tags

and for all other tags use `.html()`

So use

```
$("#tarea").val(atob(data.xmlString));
```